# Asio difference between prefer, require and make_work_guard

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

In the following example I start a worker thread for my application. Later I post some work to it. To prevent it from returning prematurely I have to ensure "work" is outstanding. I do this with a work_guard object. However I have found two other ways to "ensure" work. Which one should I use throughout my application? Is there any difference?

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <syncstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main() {
  asio::io_context workerIO;
  boost::thread workerThread;
  {
    // ensure the worker io context stands by until work is posted at a later time
    // one of the below is needed for the worker to execute work which one should I use?
    auto prodWork = asio::make_work_guard(workerIO);
    // prodWork.reset(); // can be cleared
    asio::any_io_executor prodWork2 = asio::prefer(workerIO.get_executor(), asio::execution::outstanding_work_t::tracked);
    // prodWork2 = asio::any_io_executor{}; // can be cleared
    asio::any_io_executor prodWork3 = asio::require(workerIO.get_executor(), asio::execution::outstanding_work_t::tracked);
    // prodWork3 = asio::any_io_executor{}; // can be cleared

    workerThread = boost::thread{[&workerIO] {
      std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Worker RUN START: " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
      workerIO.run();
      std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Worker RUN ENDED: " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
    }};
    asio::io_context appIO;


    std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Main RUN START: " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;

    // schedule work here
    auto timer = asio::steady_timer{appIO};
    timer.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(4));
    timer.async_wait([&workerIO] (auto ec) {
      std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Main: timer expired " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
      asio::post(workerIO.get_executor(), [] {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Worker WORK DONE " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
      });
      std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Main: work posted to worker " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
    });

    appIO.run();
    std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Main RUN ENDED: " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
  }
  workerThread.join(); // wait for the worker to finish its posted work
  std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "Main EXIT: " << std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Are there any examples for how and when to use asio::prefer and asio::require?

Docs:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard.html

Comment: Just the intention counts for me. "prefer" nor "require" express intent.

Comment: Ok interesting. Is there a difference between prefer and require? As I see it those two functions are for applying properties to executers. What are those properties? Are there any examples using these functions?

Comment: There are examples using these functions. I found out some time that not all examples are listed in the docs, so be sure to look at the `libs/asio/example` tree. I think I remember the most common use is when interacting with the `system_executor` as a singleton execution context, there. There's also a lot of tests surrounding executor concepts, but they didn't really add as much insight for me, as far as I recall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My knowledge comes from e.g. WG22 P0443R12  *["A Unified Executors Proposal for C++"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0443r12.html)*.

Some differences up front: a work-guard

- does not alter the executor, instead just calling `on_work_started()` and `on_work_finished()` on it. [It is possible to have an executor on which both of these have no effect.]
- can be `reset()` independent of its lifetime, or that of any executor instance. Decoupled lifetime is a feature.

On the other hand, using prefer/require to apply `outstanding_work` sub-properties:

- modifies existing executors
- notably when copied, all copies will have the same properties. This could be dangerous for something as invasive as keeping an execution context/resources around.

### Scanning The Field

However, not all properties are requirable in the first place. Doing some reconaissance using `Ex` defined as:

```
using namespace boost::asio::execution;
using boost::asio::io_context;
using Ex = io_context::executor_type;
```

First and foremost, check what properties can even be required/preferred (***all static assertions shown pass***):

```
using namespace boost::asio::execution;
static_assert(not outstanding_work_t::is_preferable);
static_assert(not outstanding_work_t::is_requirable);
static_assert(outstanding_work_t::untracked_t::is_preferable);
static_assert(outstanding_work_t::tracked_t::is_requirable);
```

So far so good. Let's also check that the properties apply to `Ex`:

```
static_assert(boost::asio::is_applicable_property_v<Ex, outstanding_work_t::tracked_t>);
static_assert(boost::asio::is_applicable_property_v<Ex, outstanding_work_t::untracked_t>);
```

Excellent. Observe that it's default value is untracked:

```
static_assert(outstanding_work.static_query<Ex>() != outstanding_work.tracked);
static_assert(outstanding_work.static_query<Ex>() == outstanding_work.untracked);
```

Indeed, requiring untracked doesn't change the executor type, but requiring `tracked` does:

```
boost::asio::io_context ioc;

using boost::asio::require;
auto ex           = ioc.get_executor();
auto untracked_ex = require(ex, outstanding_work.untracked);
auto tracked_ex   = require(ex, outstanding_work.tracked);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<Ex, decltype(untracked_ex)>);
static_assert(not std::is_same_v<Ex, decltype(tracked_ex)>);
```

The difference is that the `Bits` template argument for `io_context::basic_executor_type` became `4`, which does match expectations:

```
  struct io_context_bits
  {
    BOOST_ASIO_STATIC_CONSTEXPR(uintptr_t, blocking_never = 1);
    BOOST_ASIO_STATIC_CONSTEXPR(uintptr_t, relationship_continuation = 2);
    BOOST_ASIO_STATIC_CONSTEXPR(uintptr_t, outstanding_work_tracked = 4);
    BOOST_ASIO_STATIC_CONSTEXPR(uintptr_t, runtime_bits = 3);
  };
```

Now, it **does** seem that the tracked executor has a similar observable effect as a `executor_work_guard`:

```
timed_run("No work guard", [] {
    io_context ioc;
    Ex ex = ioc.get_executor();
    ioc.run_for(1s);
});

timed_run("Work guard", [] {
    io_context ioc;
    Ex ex = ioc.get_executor();
    auto w = make_work_guard(ex);
    ioc.run_for(1s);
});

timed_run("Tracked executor", [] {
    io_context ioc;
    auto ex = require(ioc.get_executor(), outstanding_work.tracked);
    
    ioc.run_for(1s);
});
```

Indeed, we can check that the observable property of "locking" execution context is propagated to copies:

```
timed_run("Copied tracked executor", [] {
    io_context ioc;

    auto original = std::make_optional(
        require(ioc.get_executor(), outstanding_work.tracked));

    auto copy = *original;

    original.reset();

    ioc.run_for(1s);
});
```

Prints

```
No work guard: 0ms
Work guard: 1000ms
Tracked executor: 1000ms
Copied tracked executor: 1000ms
```

However, is it actually the same?

## Deep Dive

The reason I'm not convinced it's semantically the same, even after the above superficial confirmations, is the wording in the paper:

[image]

Highlighting some parts:

> The existence of the executor object represents an indication of ***likely*** future submission of a function object. The executor or its associated execution context ***may choose*** to maintain execution resources in anticipation of this submission.

And specifically in the *Note*:

> [*Note*: The `outstanding_work_t::tracked_t` and `outstanding_work_t::untracked_t` properties are used to communicate to the associated execution context intended future work submission on the executor. The intended effect of the properties is the behavior of execution context’s facilities for awaiting outstanding work; specifically ***whether it considers [...] outstanding work*** when deciding what to wait on. However this will be largely ***defined by the execution context implementation***.

All in all, the main idea I get here is that:

- an executor with `tracked_t` property indicates **likelihood** of future work, but **isn't work**
- the implementation of the execution context defines whether that difference is observable

Deep-diving for our chosen execution context and executor type:

```
/// Executor implementation type used to submit functions to an io_context.
template <typename Allocator, uintptr_t Bits>
class io_context::basic_executor_type :
  detail::io_context_bits, Allocator
{
public:
  /// Copy constructor.
  basic_executor_type(
      const basic_executor_type& other) BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT
    : Allocator(static_cast<const Allocator&>(other)),
      target_(other.target_)
  {
    if (Bits & outstanding_work_tracked)
      if (context_ptr())
        context_ptr()->impl_.work_started();
  }
```

As you can see for this particular case the executor with  `outstanding_work.tracked` **does** end up with the same behavior as a `executor_work_guard<>` for that same executor/execution context.

### SUMMARY/CONCLUSIONS

So, for all intents and purposes the only **pure**/**correct** way to make a work-guard is using `executor_work_guard<>`.

However, for some execution contexts and executors the effect may be similar.

This might also be a good time to reiterate [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194070/asio-difference-between-prefer-require-and-make-work-guard/71210302#comment125853027_71194070) that `executor_work_guard` expresses intent, and has some other advantages listed at the top.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I understood it. I will surely make use of similar static_asserts in the future. Asio is a really cool library but the distributed documentation is a bit unpleasant.
What test framework is the timed_run function from?

Comment: Oh it was my own. I forgot to include the live demo - I was cramped for time. Here it is: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/c383osjxq)